# sql query - find distinct user from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve a problem using SQL query and need some expert's advice.

I have below transaction table.

```
-- UserID, ProductId, TransactionDate
--   1   ,    2     ,  2014-01-01
--   1   ,    3     ,  2014-01-05
--   2   ,    2     ,  2014-01-02
--   2   ,    3     ,  2014-05-07
           .
           .
           .
```

What I am trying to achieve is to find all user who purchased more than one product **WITHIN 30 DAYS** .

My query so far is like

```
select UserID, COUNT(distinct ProductID)
from tableA
GROUP BY UserID HAVING COUNT(distinct ProductID) > 1
```

I am not sure where to apply "WITH IN 30 DAYS" logic in the query .

The outcome should be :

```
1, 2
2, 1
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean a calendar month?

Comment: I will update the post. Let's say 30 days.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on *Within 30 Days*?

Comment: @superted do you mean within any 30 day period?

Comment: I will update the post ..

Comment: Is the last purchase included in this *30 days period*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: Within 30 Days*

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c599f/1/0)

```
SELECT
    a.UserID, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID)
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UserID, TransactionDate = MAX(TransactionDate)
    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY UserID
) AS t
    ON t.UserID = a.UserID
    AND a.TransactionDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, t.TransactionDate)
    AND a.TransactionDate <= t.TransactionDate
GROUP BY a.UserID
```

---

You can use `GROUP BY YEAR(TransactionDate), MONTH(TransactionDate)`

```
SELECT 
    UserID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID)
FROM TableA
GROUP BY 
    UserID, YEAR(TransactionDate), MONTH(TransactionDate)
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) > 1
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem when transaction date falls in different month but still within (let's say 30 days) a month range.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on *Within 30 Days*?. I'll update my post later.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a where clause.

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) cnt
FROM tableA
WHERE TransactionDate >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()) AS DATE)
GROUP BY UserID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) > 1
```

This works because the where clause is performed BEFORE the Group By and Having. So first it filters out all transactions over 30 days old and then returns only people who bought two distinct products.

Query Processing Order:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/